# Creating abstraction around data-binding libraries like AngularJS/KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, knockout.js

I just finished watching this video of Nicholas Zakas regarding scalable JavaScript Application Architecture (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXjVFPosQHw)
I am working on a project which involves jQuery + (AngularJS or KnockoutJS). We can think of creating abstraction around jQuery such that I can replace jQuery with, say, Dojo according to my client's requirements. But how can we create abstractions around libraries like AngularJS or knockoutJS, so that my application is less prone to huge modifications when I choose or replace either of these libraries.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Why do you want to create those abstractions? Why do you want to complicate your life? :)

Comment: @Ivancho: I seriously don't intend to :). But in future, If I may have to replace say KnockoutJS with AngularJS or viceversa, what measures should I take (for example, creating any abstraction if possible).

Comment: I want to add to the other answers this: don't try to over-design or over-engineer things, don't create abstractions without obvious purpose. You will thank yourself later when you don't have to cope with one more thing that doesn't bring you anything of value.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Ivancho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the `declarative` vs `imperative` nature of Angular, abstraction of the library is going to be tricky in the view templates. You shouldn't think of AngularJS as a library, but more of a framework that is part of a larger tech stack.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I share the same thought as yours. Just wanted to ensure whether they might be some way innovated by someone to achieve this.

Comment: Anup - I'm pretty sure that wrapping Angular goes against the entire point of why it was created and how it is to be used. I haven't seen any abstractions for Angular.

Answer (score 2):

Creating an abstraction around jQuery or Dojo makes sense because they are trying to accomplish the same thing, manipulating the DOM or changing HTML.

However, Angular and Knockout are client-side *frameworks*. The goals of each framework are completely different. Therefore making an abstraction around them doesn't really make much sense to me.

I would figure out what your client wants, carefully pick the framework that fits the requirements, and stick to it.

Comment: Thanks jbarnett, I understand your point.